# How can I craft weapons and armor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, crafting, armor

How does one craft weapons and armor in D&D? Assume I have a high enough crafting skill to create the item: how do I know what materials I need? What is required to make say, standard scalemail armor?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Mundane Item Crafting, Step-by-Step

These rules use exclusively the *Player's Handbook* and *Dungeon Master's Guide*. I'll gladly upvote answers that take on official sources beyond these.

1. **Get artisan's tools (*PH* 129) (5 gp; 5 lbs.).** Luckily, you might only ever need one set, though check with the DM. The description says that a set "includes the items needed to pursue any craft (except alchemy)." It says *any craft* not *all crafts*, so making characters buy artisan's tools for each Craft skill specialty isn't just the DM being a jerk. But you should *always* have artisan's tools, as it's better to be safe than sorry. Making Craft skill checks *without* artisan's tools means taking a -2 penalty to Craft skill checks "if you can do the job at all," which is code to permit the DM to say *No* when a naked character tries to use found improvised tools to make a Craft (gemcutting) skill check ("Axebeard MacDwarf'll just hit the raw diamonds with *other* raw diamonds!") or a Craft (painting) skill check ("The human body contains over 30 different fluids—one *must* be puce!").
2. **Determine if the Craft skill is appropriate.** If the plan is to make a spoon, and only the Craft (weaponsmithing) skill is available, ending up with a [weaponized spoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemian_earspoon), while possible with a generous DM, is unlikely. What skills can be used to create certain items is sometimes hotly debated (note the lack of ammunition on the *PH* 71 table), and it's debatable what some Craft skills mechanically even *do* (e.g. Craft (gemcutting)). Further, the Craft skill encompasses making works of impractical art, meaning the painter and poet use the same rules as the blacksmith and stonemason. (By the way, alchemical items can only be crafted by spellcasters; that's shameful and should be house-ruled, but that's what the game says.) Anyway—and finally—whether it's the Craft (mapmaking), Knowledge (geography), Profession (cartographer), or Survival skill—or *any* of those!—to *create a new map* (maybe even one suitable for framing) is a mystery. (In my campaigns, I like creatures to use the Craft (mapmaking) skill because that lets them sell maps they've made, but ask your DM.)
3. **Determine the item's price.** Usually, this is available. If you want something masterwork, add the masterwork cost to the item now; adding masterwork is *not* possible post-crafting. Sometimes, however, you *can't* find a price. Art objects (*DMG* 55) are particularly weird, essentially letting the crafter *set* the price for the finished item. How far down the weird little crafting rabbit hole the DM wants to go might mean craftsmen who make embroidered-and-jeweled gloves *always* make embroidered-and-jeweled gloves priced between 1,000 and 4,000 gp. (My cousin the painter tells me art prices depend on where the art's sold not on art quality, so being able to set the price of her art *before she started* would seriously *blow her mind*.)
4. **Buy raw materials.** Raw materials are usually purchased, and usually cost *one-third* the price of the finished product. DMs of realistic campaigns will quantify raw materials (e.g. greatsword raw materials, oil painting raw materials, etc.), DMs of cinematic campaigns won't (e.g. Craft (weaponsmithing) raw materials, Craft (gemcutting) raw materials, even just *raw materials* proper). Crafting in *D&D 3.5e* is such a chore I argue in favor of generosity and the cinematic.
5. **Determine the Difficulty Class (DC).** The key is using the chart "or have the DM set one." The *PH* has nothing higher than 25 (71), and I can't find in the *DMG* any higher than 40 (76), so talk the DM down if he sets DCs at 120 or something… or *don't*; see below. If you must, have him compare *anything* to the crushing wall trap (*DMG* 74), which is only DC 35 and explain how you're painting the duke's portrait, not building a death machine (unless the duke's portrait *is* a death machine… then never mind). The crafter can choose to increase the DC by 10; this will craft the item more quickly but, obviously, make success less likely. Ask the DM if this +10 can be added multiple times; I allow it as a house rule.
6. **Determine how much time's available.** If you only have a day, convert the item's price to copper pieces (i.e. multiply its gp price by 100). If you have a week, convert the item's price to silver pieces (multiply its gp price by 10). As a house rule, I let PCs also track progress by the hour (i.e. multiply by 800); less than an hour I rarely bother with unless it's something weird like a flirt sketch.
7. **Make a Craft skill check.** The DC's already been set. Success means you've spent raw materials and have made progress. Failure by 1 to 4 means no progress. Failure by 5 or more ruins half the raw materials (even if you're working by the day). I'd suggest taking 10, but the DM may rule that doing so is generally impossible (e.g. "Crafting is *always* stressful") or impossible given circumstances (e.g. "It's difficult to work whilst the orcs whip you").
8. **Determine progress based on the Craft check's result.** Multiply the check's result by DC needed to craft the item; that's 1 week's progress toward the item in silver pieces, or 1 day's progress toward the item in copper pieces. If you meet the item's price, it's completed. If progress is double the item's price, the item's completed in half the time; if progress is triple, one-third the time; and so on using *D&D 3.5*'s rules for multiplying (*PH* 304).

---

#### Let's Craft Scale Mail!

Axebeard MacDwarf is Int 10 with 7 ranks in the Craft (armorsmithing) skill. He has masterwork artisan's tools. He has a +2 racial bonus to Craft skills related to metal, and there's metal in scale mail. His total skill bonus for the Craft (armorsmithing) skill when making scale mail is +11. MacDwarf buys scale mail raw materials, costing an inconvenient sum that the DM permits him to acquire for only 16 gp. The DC for making scale mail is 14. MacDwarf has a week, so he takes it, converting the 50 gp price of scale mail to 500 sp. He takes 10 on the Craft (armorsmithing) skill check for a result of 21. He's made 21 × 14 = 294 sp of progress on his scale mail. Give him another week, and he's done. If he wanted to—or if he was interrupted—, he could track progress by the day, and by taking 10 make 294 cp of progress per day; it will take MacDwarf *more* than a week if he takes individual days to complete the scale mail at that pace, however.

#### Let's Craft A Picture of That Lady!

The Crimson Lothario wants to impress a lady. He is Int 18 with 10 ranks in Craft (painting) and has Craft (painting) artisan's tools, for a total bonus of +14. Crim set his own price on the painting of 100 gp, and the DM lets him spend only 33 gp on raw materials. Crim's player asks the DM what the DC for nice painting is. The DM consults the table on *PH* 71 and picks 15. Because he doesn't have a model to work from, the DM rules Crim can't take 10. Crim wants to work by the day (he's got adventures to go on, after all) so the painting's value in cp is 10,000. The first day he spends painting Crim rolls a 15 for a result of 29, making 15 × 29 = 435 cp of progress on the painting. After he returns from an adventure, he has a week off, so he paints and rolls a 3 for a result of 17, making 15 × 17 = 255 sp progress on the painting. Hey, a few more weeks (like, *three*) and he'll be done.

---

## "Wait a minute. *That* means…?!"

If you've gotten this far, you might have noticed some—let's be fair—*strangeness* in these rules. You've noticed that the higher the Craft DC of the item (i.e. the harder it is to make), the *faster* it can be made. So setting DCs arbitrarily high isn't always bad thing if by taking 10 the craftsman can still beat the DC. Yes, that means most DMs will rule it's faster for a craftsman to make thieves' tools than it is 10 ft. lengths of chain because most DMs will set the DC for the thieves' tools higher (probably a high quality item) than the DC for the chain (probably a typical item).

That's kind of okay. The number of folks who can consistently make lengths of chain far outnumber the folks who can consistently make thieves' tools, so it's not like there's a thieves' tools glut and chain shortage or anything. But it *is* still weird.

Welcome to *D&D 3.5e* economics.

## "O, that's too much work!"

You're right. That's why there are shops. But, besides that, *you* can make it *less* work. Untrained hirelings cost 1 sp per day, and the Craft skill can be used untrained (*PH* 64). Your hirelings will need artisan's tools (probably) but using the rules for aid another (*PH* 65-6) should allow you to simply *buy* success. The DM may limit the number of assistants you can have (perhaps to just 1 if the DM's stingy about the bonuses from favorable circumstances (*PH* 64)), but it's an option, especially if you're *that* close to being able to beat the DC by 10.

The best way to speed this process is *via* the spells [*fabricate*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#fabricate) [trans] (*PH* 229), [*minor creation*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#minor-creation) [trans] (*PH* 253-4), [*major creation*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#major-creation) [trans] (*PH* 252), and *true creation* [trans] (*SpC* 224). The DM, however, when using even these spells may still mandate appropriate Craft skill checks for complex items.

### "But where does firewood come from?"

You chop wood with an improvised tool and use the Craft (carpentry) skill check untrained. Firewood costs 1 cp; fractions round down; one-third of a cp is 0 cp; raw materials are free. The DM rules that crafting firewood is DC 5. Spend the day karate chopping trees, taking 10 on the Craft (carpentry) skill check for a result of 8 x 5 = 40 cp of progress made per day (essentially, you're making 1 check every 12 min.). Make 40 cp (*800 lbs.*) of firewood in a day. Sell that firewood for half price (as per *D&D* Econ 101) and earn 2 sp. Buy a poor meal (1 sp) and 2 mugs of ale (8 cp total) and put the remaining 2 cp away for a rainy day. Congratulations, peasant. You're alive. I hope your family home isn't threatened by an owlbear so you can continue to take 10.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67415/discussion-on-answer-by-hey-i-can-chan-how-can-i-craft-weapons-and-armor).

Answer (score 1):

I take it you've already worked out how the mechanical process of calculating progress for your crafting tasks work - at least, some passage in your question tells me you have. If not, tell me and I will update my answer.

---

To create, say, standard scalemail armor you need some "materials for crafting armors". These are non-descript (the game does not *usually* care about this level of detail) and their cost is defined by the cost of your final product.

In the vast majority of crafting, you need to buy these materials from someone, with a few exceptions being maybe dragon scales that you can actually take from a slain dragon.

The Craft (metallurgy) and Craft (metalworking) skills can be used to provide raw materials for any metallic armor or weapon (metallurgy goes from raw material to metal, metalworking turns the ingots into workable material), which means you caould, given enough time, create some raw materials yourself.
The gain is minimal, since you're spending days to save a minimal amount of money, but it is nonetheless useful to explain how NPCs actually make those nondescript materials.

Comment: I usually see metallurgy rolled up into Craft (metalworking); I don’t think the game has that level of detail, either. Do you have any source that suggests they’re “supposed” to be separate?

Comment: @KRyan I'm sure I've seen a rules-reliable guy in a forum I'm in talk about this very thing. I'm going to ask him what his sources are as soon as he logs Skype in. Until then, I suppose some PrC requires them or they're both listed in craft example lists.